# Customise UIActivityViewController IOS6

Tags: ios6

I have created a `UIActivityViewController`, and wondering if its possible to change the color of the navigation bar when the Mail-Composer is presented ?

I have tried this for example:

```
activityViewController.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

But nothing seems to work

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change color across the board you can do something like [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:yourColor];